# C# version of preg_match

Tags: c#

just new to c#..i need some help .. im trying to convert this to C#  but don't know what is equivalent of preg_match_all in C#..been reading some books but i don't get it..:'(

```
$pattern =
    '@' . 
    '<td>\s*' .
    '(?P<no>\d+)\.\s*' .
    '</td>\s*' .
    '<td>\s*' .
    '<a class="LN" href="[^"]*+" onclick="[^"]*+">\s*+' .
    '<b>(?P<name>[^<]*+)</b>\s*+' .
    '</a>.*\s*' .
    '</td>\s*+' .
    '<td align="center">[^<]*+</td>\s*+' .
    '<td>\s*+' .
    '(?P<locations>(?:<a href="[^"]*+">[^<]*+</a><br />\s*+)++)' .
    '</td>' .
    '@'
    ;

    $results = array();
    preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
    foreach ($matches as $i => $match) {
        preg_match_all('@<a href="[^"]*+">([^<]*+)</a>@', $match['locations'], $locations);
        $results[$i]['no'] = $match['no'];
        $results[$i]['name'] = $match['name'];
        $results[$i]['locations'] = $locations[1];
    }**
```

Comment: It looks like it's using regex to attempt to parse some HTML - it would be better to use a proper tool like the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Comment: how about the WebClient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must write this:

```
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(contents, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
{
    string no = match.Groups["no"].Value;
    ///...etc 
}
```

Comment: ...why do i get unrecognized escape sequence?

Comment: I think because you wrong using backslahes. Maybe it helped at start of your string add '@' For example: `string path=@"C:\Windows\system32";` It`s analog `string path = "C:\\Windows\\system32";`

Comment: thank you..now i get an error  Unrecognized grouping construct.

Comment: You must check open and closed parenthesis

Answer (score 1):

Use static method

```
public static Match Match(
    string input,
    string pattern,
    RegexOptions options
)
```

This function Return :

> [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx)  An object that contains
>   information about the match.

For more info see [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bk1x0726.aspx)